# How to get inline z-index style with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Following returns 'auto' instead of 10. Why?

```
<div class="testclass" style="z-index:10"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
  alert($(".testclass").css("z-index"));
});
</script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kEVq7/50/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently, because the div is not positioned. Make this change to your div's style:

```
<div class="testclass" style="position:absolute; z-index:10"></div>
```

And you will 10 in the alert.

This makes sense in that the z-index property doesn't apply to a non-positioned element.

By the way, this further appears to be browser-dependent behavior. Your Fiddle reports 10 under Firefox, but auto under Chrome.

Comment: Thanks dgvid! +1. I was using absolute on child element instead ot the parent in my script, thats why it did not work. Thanks again!

Comment: Accepting in 6 minutes

Answer (score 2):

z-index can only be assigned to positioned elements. Try adding:

```
.testclass {
    position:relative;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `z-index` property can only be applied to elements that have the position `absolute`, `relative` or `fixed`. Since the default property is `static` you are getting the result `auto` instead of 10

Answer (score 0):

It must be a bug in Chrome, it works in FireFox.

Just try a vanilla approach

```
$(function() {
  console.log($(".testclass").css("z-index"));
  console.log($(".testclass")[0].style.zIndex);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kEVq7/57/

There is little jQuery use in this, getting the style attribute works cross browser.

Answer (score 0):

Humm. If you want a n answer I think its a bug but the z-index is correctly set [image]

```
.testclass {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: black;
}
```

see the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rm596/kEVq7/61/)

Answer (score 0):

It's messy, but you can try this jsFiddle solution. it uses `.attr()` and `.substring` to find the value. I'm not quite sure why you cant get the inline value.

http://jsfiddle.net/kEVq7/59/

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/kEVq7/63/

here it is working with vanilla javascript

```
var x = document.querySelector('.testclass').style.zIndex;
alert(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

CSS z-index property always work with **absolute** as well as **relative** positioning value. So you must define `position:relative` or either `position:absolute`.

#### Check this <kbd>**[demo jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kEVq7/64/)**</kbd>

#### HTML

```
<div class="testclass" style="position:relative; z-index:10;"></div>
```

#### jQuery

```
$(function() {
  alert($(".testclass").css("z-index"));
});
```

---

But in your case you can use JavaScript for fast execution in compare of j-Query by using **[querySelector()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.querySelector)**

#### Check this <kbd>**[demo jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kEVq7/65/)**</kbd>

#### HTML

```
<div class="testclass" style="position:relative; z-index:10;"></div>
```

#### JavaScript

```
alert(document.querySelector('.testclass').style.zIndex);
```

Hope this both are help you!